# Unusual behavior with shift-right bitwise operator

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I'm writing a simple code in C (only using bit-wise operators) that takes a pointer to an unsigned integer `x` and flips the bit at the nth position `n` in the binary notation of the integer. The function is declared as follows:

```
int flip_bit (unsigned * x, unsigned n);
```

It is assumed that `n` is between 0 and 31.

In one of the steps, I perform a shift-right operation, but the results are not what I expect. For instance, if I do `0x8000000 >> 30`, I get `0xfffffffe` as a result, which are `1000 0000 ... 0000` and `1111 1111 ... 1110`, respectively, in binary notation. (The expected result is`0000 0000 ... 0010`).

I am unsure of how or where I am making the mistake. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Edit 1: Below is the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define INTSIZE 31

void flip_bit(unsigned * x,
          unsigned n) {

int a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, p, q;
// save bits on the left of n and insert a zero at the end
a = * x >> n + 1;
b = a << 1;

// save bits on the right of n
c = * x << INTSIZE - (n - 1);
d = c >> INTSIZE - (n - 1);

// shift the bits to the left (back in their positions) 
// combine all bits
e = d << n;
f = b | e;

// Isolating the nth bit in its position
g = * x >> n;
h = g << INTSIZE;
// THIS LINE BELOW IS THE ONE CAUSING TROUBLE.
i = h >> INTSIZE - n;

// flipping all bits and removing the 1s surrounding 
// the nth bit (0 or 1)
j = ~i;
k = j >> n;
l = k << INTSIZE;
p = l >> INTSIZE - n;

// combining the value missing nth bit and 
// the one with the flipped one
q = f | p;
* x = q;
}
```

I'm getting the unusual behavior when I run `flip_bit(0x0000004e,0)`. The line for the shift-right operation in question has comments in uppercase above it.

There is probably a shorter way to do this (without using a thousand variables), but that's what I have now.

Edit 2: The problem was that I declared the variables as `int` (instead of `unsigned`). Nevertheless, that's a terrible way to solve the question. @old_timer suggested returning `*x ^ (1u << n)`, which is much better.

Comment: I think sign extension on a shift right is implementation defined.  what compiler is this?

Comment: @old_timer, I'm using gcc on Ubuntu.

Comment: Post your code. Reproduce-ability!

Comment: @old_timer, I just added the code.

Comment: a = * x >> n + 1;  only needed to see that one line right?

Comment: if you are flipping a bit why not xor with 1<<n and be done with it?  *x^=1<<n;

Comment: @MichaelPetch, you're right. That's where the mistake was.

Comment: which was pointed out in my example (we assumed that is what was going on, but needed confirmation).

Comment: anything orred with a 1 is one, anything orred with a 0 is itself.  Anything anded with 1 is itself anything anded with 0 is zero, anything xored with 0 is itself anything xored with 1 is inverted.  has nothing to do with C.

Comment: Instead of `int a, b, c, d, e, ....`, use `unsigned int a, b, c, d, e, ...`

Comment: `*x ^ (1u << n)` is a better way - notice `u`.  This avoids all signed math issues.

Comment: `* x` -> `*x`. Spaces are fine, but one should know when they improve readability and when they do the opposite..

Comment: @old_timer: "I think sign extension on a shift right is implementation defined" - only for signed integers. Which most of the variables happen to be.

Comment: @M.M, I meant the number of steps involved in my original answer. It's too long compared to old_timer's suggestion.

Comment: @amucunguzi Ah yes. Good observation :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that you're performing a right shift on a signed `int`.

From section 6.5.7 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> *5* The result of E1 >> E2 is E1 right-shifted E2 bit positions. If E1 has an unsigned type or if E1 has a signed type and a nonnegative
>   value, the value of the result is the integral part of the quotient of
>   E1 / 2<sup>E2</sup>. **If E1 has a signed type and a negative value, the
>   resulting value is implementation-defined.**

The bold part is what's happening in your case.  Each of your intermediate variables are of type `int`.  Assuming your system uses 2's complement representations for negative numbers, any `int` value with the high bit set is interpreted as a negative value.

The most common implementation-defined behavior behavior you'll see (and this in fact what [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.5/gcc/Integers-implementation.html#Integers-implementation) and [MSVC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7x62187h.aspx) both do) in this case is that if the high bit is set on a signed value then a 1 will be shifted in on a right shift.  This preserves the sign of the value and makes x >> n equivalent to x / 2<sup>n</sup> for all signed and unsigned values.

You can fix this by changing all of your intermediate variables to `unsigned`.  That way, they match the type of `*x` and you won't get 1s pushed on to the left.

As for your method of flipping a bit, there is a much simpler way of doing so.  You can instead use the `^` operator, which is the bitwise exclusive OR operator.

From section 6.5.11 of the C standard:

> *4* The result of the `^` operator is the bitwise exclusive OR (XOR) of the
>   operands (that is, each bit in the result is set if and only if
>   exactly one of the corresponding bits in the converted operands is
>   set).

For example:

```
  0010      1000
^ 1100    ^ 1101
------    ------
  1110      0101
```

Note that you can use this to create a bitmask, then use that bitmask to flip the bits in the other operand.

So if you want to flip bit `n`, take the value 1, left shift it by `n` to move that bit to the desired location then XOR that value with your target value to flip that bit:

```
void flip_bit(unsigned * x, unsigned n) {
    return *x = *x ^ (1u << n);
}
```

You can also use the `^=` operator in this case which XORs the right operand to the left and assigns the result to the left:

```
return *x ^= (1u << n);
```

Also note the `u` suffix on the integer constant.  That causes the type of the constant to be `unsigned` which helps to avoid the implementation defined behavior you experienced.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ( void )
{
    unsigned int x;
    int y;
    x=0x80000000;
    x>>=30;
    printf("0x%08X\n",x);
    y=0x80000000;
    y>>=30;
    printf("0x%08X\n",y);
    return(0);
}
```

gcc on mint

```
0x00000002
0xFFFFFFFE
```

or what about this

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ( void )
{
    unsigned int x;
    x=0x12345678;
    x^=1<<30;
    printf("0x%08X\n",x);
}
```

output

```
0x52345678
```

Comment: still not sure that shifting a signed number in C is insured to sign extend or is "implementation defined".  Certainly this version of gcc sign extends, which was your problem mixing signed and unsigned.

Comment: It is implementation defined. GCC and MSVC in my experience do an arithmetic right shift on signed types.

Comment: `1u << 30` would be better . Moot in this case, but a good habit. The difference would matter in the case of `1u << 31` (OK) vs. `1 << 31` (undefined behaviour).